# How to iterate Arrays inside another array inside tableview cell for row

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift3

Output of array looks like  [[3, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [6, 1]]
I want particular values 3 and 1 for indexpath.row 1 and so on.

```
var weekdays = [Int]()
weekdays.append(daysArr)  

 Attempt 1
 for i in weekdays  {
      for j in i
      } 
}
```

On this line - for j in i
I get error like "Type any" does not confirm to protocol 'Sequence'

I tried changing type from any to other but nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is nested declare it as

```
var weekdays = [[Int]]()
```

In `cellForRow` get the inner array with `indexPath.row` and iterate it the usual way

```
let weekdayArray = weekdays[indexPath.row]
for aWeekday in weekdayArray {
    print(aWeekday)
}
```

Comment: Can you please confirm why question is downvote ?|
Also there is one issue with your answer i.e aWeekday[3, 1]
But how to get value 3 and 1 .. I mean how can I iterate over aWeekday

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I can imagine that people are downvoting because the question is a bit ambiguous, for example it's missing in which line the error occurs and is `weekdays` the data source array of something else? And in my example `weekdayArray` will contain `[3, 1]`. The loop is iterating over `weekdayArray`

Comment: Thanks for the info on downvote. And thanks for your solution. I am gonna accept your answer

Comment: I made changes on question, please do let me know if its correct now ?

Comment: It's much better. By the way: The error (message) occurs because you are trying to access a second level of a one-level array.

Comment: yes, I understand that now. Thanks your answer clearly explains that. If possible please up vote my question